# How can I use a Lambda Expression to calculate a function in C# with variables from multiple nodes in a LinkedList<object>?i

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LinkedList<Day> Days = new LinkedList<Day>();

    Day day1 = new Day() { sunUp = 800, sunDown = 1800 };
    Day day2 = new Day() { sunUp = 755, sunDown = 1805 };
    Day day3 = new Day() { sunUp = 750, sunDown = 1810 };
    Day day4 = new Day() { sunUp = 745, sunDown = 1815 };
    Day day5 = new Day() { sunUp = 740, sunDown = 1820 };

    Days.AddLast(day1);
    Days.AddLast(day2);
    Days.AddLast(day3);
    Days.AddLast(day4);
    Days.AddLast(day5);
    Console.WriteLine("There is an average of {0} minutes of night over the past {1} days.", Calculator(Days), Days.Count);
}
```

```
public static int ToMinutes(int time)
{
    return time / 100 * 60 + time - time / 100 * 100;
}
```

```
class Day
{
    public int sunUp;
    public int sunDown;
}
```

```
public static int Calculator(LinkedList<Day> Days)
{
    var current = Days.First;
    int nightDuration = 0;
    int count = 0; 
    while (current.Next != null)
    {
        nightDuration += ToMinutes(current.Value.sunDown) - ToMinutes(current.Next.Value.sunUp);
        current = current.Next;
        count++;
    }
    return nightDuration/count;

}
```

Requirement: Day must be stored in a LinkedList.

Is there a clean Lambda Expression equivalent to the Calculator method above? I am having trouble using Lambda's to calculate a function with variables across connected nodes.

Thanks for the help!

Cheers,
Kyle

Comment: I realize this is pseudo-code. But, you *really* don't want to have a class called `Object`; you'll get name collisions with `System.Object`

Comment: check this for lambda expression :   https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-lambda-expression

Comment: I'd appreciate some insight into why my question is getting downvoted so I can improve my posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried various methods but realized that at the end of the day, your data is just a list, not a linked list. It would be easier to use method like you have for this kind of structure (unless someone else can give you a better answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few things are wrong with your pseudo code of using a calculator (for addition in this instance)

You have a class that has two integers. I believe your idea is to add the two numbers together along with two numbers from every other node of the linked list. But, you are adding only the first number from Pair and adding it to 2nd number of the next node... dont think it will work.

```
array = current.value.int1 + current.Next.value.int2;
```

should be

```
array = current.value.int1 + current.value.int2;
```

**Working Example**

```
    public static int Calculator(LinkedList<Pair> Pairs)
    {
        var current = Pairs.First;
        int sum = 0;
        while (current != null)
        {
            sum += current.Value.num1 + current.Value.num2;
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Ran this in the main,

```
    LinkedList<Pair> Pairs = new LinkedList<Pair>();
    Pair pair = new Pair() { num1 = 1, num2 = 5 };
    Pairs.AddFirst(pair);
    Pairs.AddLast(pair);
    Pairs.AddLast(pair);
    Console.WriteLine( Calculator(Pairs));
```

**Output**

```
18
```

**Lambda expression** you can use to add up all the linked lists can be summed up as,

```
Console.WriteLine(Pairs.Sum(x => x.num1 + x.num2));
```

**Output**

```
18
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me.  I've updated my post to hopefully show a clearer picture of what I'm looking for. You were close, just missing a couple of items. Completely my fault for not being clear in my example. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have a lambda expression at the end of my post, is that not what you need?

Comment: It is, but that expression does not achieve what I am looking for. I updated my example to represent a real-world problem. Hopefully, this helps clarify what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example i see what you're trying to say. So you want to the same logic as in your Calculator method but using Lambda expression. The most easy way to do this is to use Language Integrated Query (LINQ).

So breaking up your Calculator() method we see it actually contains 2 elements.

1. Sum up each value after you've combined num1 with num2 in the List
2. Divide the end result with the total count in the list.

The most easy way to do this is by using Enumerable.Sum and then devide that value by the count of the list. For example:

```
Pairs.Sum(pair => pair.num1 + pair.num2) / Pairs.Count

Result: 6
```

[Here a code example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x3xkqN)

> Enumerable.Sum is extension method from System.Linq namespace. It returns sum of numeric values in collection.

Although Lambda expressions are awesome, please do bare in mind that readability is also very important. They are basically anonymous functions which, if the logic gets complex, will be hard to understand for other developers/team members.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

---

**EDIT**

So if i understand it correctly you're having a hard time using lambda expressions with nested methods. Like for example your Calculator() method makes use of another method ToMinutes.

Using the code from my first example, we can still use the logic. The most important part we have to change is the logic within the Sum. E.g.

```
Days.Sum(day => ToMinutes(day.sunDown) - ToMinutes(day.sunUp )) / totalDays;
```

This is just one of the ways to do it. Another option is to create an ExtensionMethod. E.g.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class IntExtensions
     {
        public static int ToMinutes(this int time)
        {
            return time / 100 * 60 + time - time / 100 * 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Above the class you want to use the extension method just include it by writing

```
using ExtensionMethods;
```

at the top of your document.

This will give another option to all your integers to parse the value to a different value. In our case, to minutes.

```
int totalDays = Days.Count;
int averageMinutes = Days.Sum(day => day.sunDown.ToMinutes() - day.sunUp.ToMinutes()) / totalDays;
Console.WriteLine("There is an average of {0} minutes of night over the past {1} days.", averageMinutes, totalDays);
```

But again. This is one of the ways of doing it. I would recommend you to get and read [C# in Depth](https://csharpindepth.com/) by Jon Skeet and also dive into the clean code principles.

Anyways, i think i have made myself clear. See [example code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R420VD) for more details.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Scircia. I've updated my example to show my problem, hopefully, better. My issue is that I can't figure out how to include variables from multiple connected nodes in the lambda expression.

Comment: As i have said before. readability is very important, so don't try to use Lambda for everything. That aside. I have changed some of your code. I'll ediy my answer explaining what i did. There are many ways to solve this, it all depends on usage, readability, preferences, etc. But i think you'll roughly understand where i'm going to.